# Share images between users

Tags: users

Please is there a Drupal module that allows users to share images with each other privately? I know the [Private Message module](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg)  allows users to send messages privately to each other. Thats fine, but i need users to also send images to each other privately in addition to messages.

Thank you.

Comment: Using Private Message module you can send images/files as an attachment. Just introduce one field in message entity

Comment: Use [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) so you can attach images.